# How to hyperlink a table data in a cell in php

Tags: php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" '<a href="http://localhost/Test/AddLocation.php">. $row['id'] .</a>'</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LayarType'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Attribution'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
  }
```

it gives an error...

how do i give a link suggested here in bold part..

Answer (score 2):

You were not concatenating the different strings with the `.` operator.

Either of the following will work:

```
echo "<td>" . '<a href="http://localhost/Test/AddLocation.php">'. $row['id'] .'</a>' .  "</td>";
// or
echo '<td><a href="http://localhost/Test/AddLocation.php">'. $row['id'] .'</a></td>';
```

Comment: sir, the same goes further...now i want to pass this cell data ( in hyperlink) to a redirected page..here it is in addlocation.php...how do i get this data in addlocation page..??

Comment: @alpest: I suggest you [read about PHP strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), as it is something that should be learnt early on.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are messed up in the second echo.

Also, for strings with no variables inside them, [you should use single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) instead of double quotes so that PHP doesn't have to process the contents.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><a href="http://localhost/Test/AddLocation.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'. $row['id'] .'</a></td>';        echo '<td>' . $row['LayarType'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Attribution'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: sir, the same goes further...now i want to pass this cell data ( in hyperlink) to a redirected page..here it is in addlocation.php...how do i get this data in addlocation page..??

Comment: I edited the solution to pass the row['id'] to AddLocation.php. Is that what you want?